# Different behavior for .mps and .eps

Tags: graphics, pdf, includegraphics, eps, epstopdf

The following example document loads two identical graphics files as .mps and .eps via `\includegraphics`. Both are valid eps files.  I get different results depending on the TeX compiler, but always unexpected ones:

1. pdflatex & lualatex: first square is red, second square is black
2. xelatex: Both squares are black
3. latex+dvips+ps2pdf: Both squares are black

I would expect only red squares since there is no coloring in the postscript code, or at least all results should be the same. Any Comments?

```
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{foo.mps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 1000 1000 
%%Page: 1 1
newpath 0 0 moveto
1000 0 lineto
1000 1000 lineto
0 1000 lineto
closepath fill
showpage
%%EOF
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{foo.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 1000 1000 
%%Page: 1 1
newpath 0 0 moveto
1000 0 lineto
1000 1000 lineto
0 1000 lineto
closepath fill
showpage
%%EOF
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}    
\begin{document}
  \color{red!70}
  \rule{10mm}{30mm}\hfill \includegraphics[height=30mm]{foo.mps} \hfill 
  \includegraphics[height=30mm]{foo.eps} \hfill \rule{10mm}{30mm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the mps is used directly by pdflatex, but the eps is converted by ghostscript to pdf, and ghostscript adds `0 g` to the stream. I don't know if ghostscript has an option to avoid that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Even if there is such option, I guess there is no way to inherit the color from the outer scope (red in this example) for EPS?